# Can't close the previous Frame

Tags: java

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
   new Login().setVisible(true);
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer(500 ,taskPerformer);`enter code here`
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
```

I wrote this code to start a Frame for 0.5 seconds and then switch to the next frame but when the timer ends I does switch to the Login frame but does not close the Start frame. I've tried disposing but this results in infinite frames running endlessly.
Please Help.. It's for my Project.

Comment: Where is your previous Frame?

Comment: I set it to dispose but it didn't work. and when I tried putting "new Start().dispose();" OR "new Start().setVisible(false);"
It started running endlessly open both the frames again and again.

Comment: Thank You so Much Murat K. Sir.. I am really thankful that u took the pain of writing to me. but I solved this problem. 
FYI
Created a method "void close(){ this.setVisible(false)}"
and called it in the event formDeactivated